# PyQt6: How do you close a QApplication and then reopen it after? Or how do you reset position and input boxes in a window to original?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt6

I’m new to PyQt6 and I’m trying to create a login screen.
Whenever I try to reopen my MainWindow after closing it, it prints out "QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running" in the Shell.
Am I even opening it right and/or how do I open it again? Also/instead, how could I reset the position of the window to the original size and position and reset the text input fields for the username and password the being empty.
Any help would be appreciated!

When I press the button that displays "Exit", the window should ideally close and then be reopened (this I have tried in the function when the button is pressed). I want to do that to be able to reset the position of the window to its assigned position and reset the text input fields for the username and password, which I’m assuming would happen if I close and reopen the window.
(The password and username are compared to a Database but that is not involved in this situation.)

My code:

```
import sys
from sqlite3 import *

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
                             QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

file = connect("login_db.db")
cursor = file.cursor()
location = """SELECT * FROM Login"""
cursor.execute(location)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print("All records:",records)


class AnotherWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Another Window")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 120, 251, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 120, 71, 41))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 180, 71, 41))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 180, 251, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 240, 151, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")

        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 240, 151, 51))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")

        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.login_f)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.exit_pro)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
    def exit_pro(self):
        MainWindow.close()

        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        z = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(z)
        z.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())


    def login_f(self):
        username = self.lineEdit.text()
        password = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        if username == "" or password == "":
            print("You haven't entered your username or password")
            valid_inp = False
        else:
            valid_inp = True
        user_found = False
        pass_right = False
        if valid_inp == True:
            for row in records:
                if username == row[0]:
                    user_found = True
                    if row[1] == password:
                        pass_right = True
            if user_found == False or pass_right == False:
                print("wrong username or password")
            elif user_found == True and pass_right == True:
                print("Right password and username")
    
    
    
    
    def show_new_window(self, checked):
        w = AnotherWindow()
        w.show()
        
    
    

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Username:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Password:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Log in"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Why are you trying to open another application? Just call `show()` on the window you closed before.

Comment: Thank you, that does reopen the window, however it doesn't clear the text input fields. Do you know how that could be achieved?

Comment: Clear them manually by calling their respective functions.